# Spring Hibernate JPA Java8 OffsetTime

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, java-8, timezone-offset

I have created an Hibernate Entity which has a OffsetTime column. While saving a time value with time offset e.g (+05:00), it discards time offset, and saves the time with the time offset according to the system timezone. Here is my column in entity:

```
@Column(name = "start_time", nullable = false)
private OffsetTime startTime;
```

Then if I try to save "12:15+01:00". It save "12:15+00:00", if my machine is in UTC timezone, if my machine is in IST timezone, it save "12:15+05:00". I want it to save "12:15+01:00" irrespective of machine's timezone.

Please suggest what I need to correct/review to ensure I fix this issue.

Thanks.

Comment: Which data base do you use?

Comment: If you're using MySQL, it does NOT store timezone offset and just cuts it off. You're better off storing it as an Epoch long integer or converting everything to UTC.

Answer (score 0):

Question is how do you do the setting of the value. You didn't show your setter method. You either parse it from `String` or operate some instance of `Temporal` that you convert to `OffsetTime` in either case you will need to provide the desired offset if you don't want to use the default one. Say that you want to save current time with given offset. So you will have to do this:

```
OffsetTime startTime = OffsetTime.of(LocalTime.now, ZoneOffset.of("+05:00");
```

See method [of()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/OffsetTime.html#of-java.time.LocalTime-java.time.ZoneOffset-) as well of other methods of [OffsetTime](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/OffsetTime.html)

Comment: I am receiving the time as json input in spring rest endpoint. While testing the endpoint for example in postman, I use "12:15+01:00" in json field. I see in the endpoint controller, I have correct information as "12:15+01:00", but when I call Spring Data Hibernate Repository and pass this entity, database correctly shows time "12:15+xx:xx", but the xx:xx is not what I am passing it, rather the default system timeoffset is added in the db.

Comment: In this case you can add the following  annotationjust above your @Column annotayion: 
@JsonFormat(shape= JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern="HH:mmZ")

Comment: You got it wrong I think, here is the architecture:

1. FE Service call (JSON Body contain time"12:15+01:00") => 2. Controller parses http request body to DTO => 3. controller calls service class => 3. service class converts to Entity by mapping => 4. Service class calls Spring Data Hibernate repository => 5. Spring data updates the DB

Spring deserializes the json body correctly to DTO, service calls repository with correct data, but once Spring data updates the DB, it overrides the set time offset by the default system offset.

Comment: If I was not clear in above explaination, I can retry to explain the issue to you?

Comment: Your explanation is clear. But for now I am not sure where the problem is, and that is the reason I didn't respond